# difficulty with package definition

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have the .fla file in a folder named sample.In sample i have another folder named one which contains the classes.i have set the source path for classes to this one folder.Now in the class file i have

```
 package one
{ // code
}
```

but i m geting the error "C:\Users\gaurav\Documents\sample\one\CDK.as, Line 1   5001: The name of package 'one' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\Users\gaurav\Documents\sample\one\CDK.as" ... can someone plz help me with it...

Answer (score 2):

Packages reflect an identical folder structure to your project.

If your project is in:

> C:\Users\gaurav\Documents\sample\sample.fla

`package one` would be in:

> C:\Users\gaurav\Documents\sample\one

If your package namespace root is the same as your FLA, there's no need to set a source path for classes.

If you set a source path for classes as a folder, `one` must be a child of that folder.

ie: setting source path to `one` implies `one\one` would define `package one`, as in:

> C:\Users\gaurav\Documents\sample\one\one

Otherwise, you can add a source path to your Flash for classes at a different folder location than your FLA, such as a common source folder.